# Is there a way to find a process on top of the process id and name in c#

Tags: c#, process

I have multiple processes started and I want to keep track of each of them so that I can start the process again if it ended without my knowledge.

Currently, I store the process id in my database and I use the process id and name to check if the process is still running.

```cs
Process process=Process.GetProcessById(id);
if(process.ProcessName==processName){
 //kill the process
}
```

However, I was reading online that when a process dies, its id will be free for other processes to use. There could be a chance that there will be a new process with my old process id and name which might lead me to assume my old process is still running.

Is there any additional fields I can add to make my process unique? such as the process site? I am unable to get more information on what the process site is used for.

Comment: If the processID is the one your looking for and the process name is the one you looking for....then you should be good.

Comment: Allow me to clarify what you do or do not understand about this:  are you aware that you can't technically start (or restart) a process after it ends?  You can start a _new_ process with the same parameters, but it will be a new process with a different process ID.  Also are you aware that in Windows you can open a HANDLE to a process, which will remain valid even after the process exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the [Process.StartTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.starttime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_StartTime) property in addition to its ID. That should protect you in the case that the PID has been re-used since the new process would have a different start time to the one stored.

```cs
var process = Process.GetProcessById(id);

if (process.ProcessName == processName && process.StartTime == startTime)
{
    //kill the process
}
```

---

I suspect the following does not apply since you're persisting process information, but if your application is continually monitoring these processes then you might consider using the [Process.Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.8) event to receive notifications when a process exits rather than checking every so often, e.g.

```cs
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, args) => { /* Do something */ };
```

Comment: Good solution!!

Comment: Thanks! this is what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this piece of code and look at the available properites of

```
runningProcesses
```

...

```
    private static void KillProcess(string processName)
    {
        Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
        {
            if (process.ProcessName == processName)
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
```

You could create your process with a unique **BasePriority**
 or something similar.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8)